# Why is my code to upload working locally but does not work after being uploaded to heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, heroku

I'm not really with my system to show this...

But it is that, the code is for uploading, and it works locally on locally, but on Heroku, the image being uploaded will appear but will be missing after some time

And when I check the file to which the upload is supposed to stay, it does not appear there

Answer (score 1):

I think it because the Heroku filesystem is ephemeral

reference:
[https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted#:~:text=The%20Heroku%20filesystem%20is%20ephemeral,from%20the%20most%20recent%20deploy](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted#:%7E:text=The%20Heroku%20filesystem%20is%20ephemeral,from%20the%20most%20recent%20deploy)